# "Never slap a man who's chewing tobacco"

Tags: meaning, etymology, proverbs, phrase-meaning

Is this a proverb? What does it mean and what is the origin?

Comment: Have you ever looked in a spittoon?  Would you want risk that getting on you?

Comment: Is this a proverb? From NOAD: **proverb** (*n.*) a short pithy saying in general use, stating a general truth or piece of advice. Sure looks like a proverb to me.

Comment: By the bye, this is also Francis Underwood's, from House of Cards, Season 2, Episode 9 or 10 (I don't remember).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a quote by Will Rogers, and almost anything he said (in one sentence or less) could be described as a proverb. The meaning is sort of obvious: if you slap a man who is chewing tobacco, you are likely to end up wearing it!

It would be similar to "catching a tiger by its tail". The idea being that you should not underestimate your adversary.

[About Will Rogers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_Rogers)

Comment: @ReqDwight thanks, I had stuck a <giggle> in there but I guess the parser ate it.

Comment: Maybe adding a link to Will Rogers might be helpful for non-Americans. I don't know who he is at all.

Comment: Anything written as `<text>` is interpreted as an HTML tag which is why your `<giggle>` did not appear.

Comment: @Mari-Lou Done!

Comment: Thanks, a very unique man. Do you know if there is anyone in the US who can live up to his legacy?

Comment: Unfortunately he was one of a kind - Garrison Keillor is an interesting fellow who I would say has a very similar style - but he's no Will Rogers! btw I updated that wiki to include this quote :)

I know, I know - here's the url for Garrison Keillor <g> `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garrison_Keillor`

Comment: Will Rogers was a humorist (what we'd these days call a comedian). I suppose you could consider his utterances "proverbs", but only if you are equally willing to give the same status to some of the more popular bits of Eddie Murphy and Chris Rock ("A man is basically as faithful as his options").

Answer (score 6):

It means that if a man is doing something undesirable, don't confront him upfront or you'll be negatively affected in some way or the other too.

Just like if you slap a man while he's chewing tobacco you'll get some of the dirty stuff onto yourself too

Answer (score -3):

It means that when he's chewing tobacco, he's probably in a foul mood, and it's not a good moment to confront him.

Comment: Will you provide references to support your assertion?

Comment: Please do not flag mistaken or incomplete answers. Flags should be used to alert the moderator team when the normal mechanisms for improving a post (edits, comments, and votes) are inadequate and moderator intervention is necessary.